# Document is not rolled back if transaction gets aborted Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my server I'm trying to use transactions to create orders. Before saving the order with `Order.create` I check and modify quantities in Product records, check for payment details on buyer and seller, aborting the transaction if anything goes wrong ( I omitted that part in the code sample below), but when passing the object from the request body to `Order.create` as I normally do on document creation it fails not finding requested parameters for the Order schema.

I have found here https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6761#issuecomment-437493275 and also the doc https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create say that when inside a transaction the object needs to be passed into an array ( like `await SomeModel.create([obj], { session })` ), so I suppose that as we are inside a transaction, if the transaction is aborted then the created record gets rolled back.
In my app it does create the document but it's not rolled back if I abort the transaction . In fact if I query the db with the document id just created I get the result back.

Also now my logic inside the `finally` statement is not working anymore. There, if the transaction is not aborted the if statement check on `session.inTransaction` should return `true` so there I commit the transaction and end the session. If instead the transaction is aborted it should return `false` and nothing else happens as  whenever I abort the transaction I also end the session.
When using `await SomeModel.create([obj], { session })` the if statement never returns true so the transaction is never committed and the session is never ended.

Can you see what's wrong with the code here below?

```
exports.createOrder = async (req, res) => {

    const { productIdList, productPromotionList, customerId, shopId } = req.body;

    // const order = req.body;
    var notAvailableProducts = [];
    var notAvailablePromotions = [];
    // console.log('createOreder req.body is : ', order);
    var amount = 0.00;
    var stripeAccountId = '';
    var stripeCustomerId = '';
    var receiptEmail = '';
    var defaultSource = '';
    const session = await Order.startSession();
    session.startTransaction();

    try {

... omitted part

        console.log('createOrder req.body is : ', req.body);

        // const order = 
        // await 
        Order.create(
           // req.body, // error 
            [ req.body], // works but doesn't get rolled back if transaction is aborted
            { session: session },
            function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Mongoose createOrder error:  Order.create', err);
                    res.status(503).send({ error: "Internal error" });
                    session.abortTransaction();
                    session.endSession();
                    return;
                }


                console.log('Mongoose createOrder: ', result);
                res.status(200).send({
                    message: "Order created successfully!",
                    data: result,
                    missingProducts: notAvailableProducts,
                    missingPromotions: notAvailablePromotions
                });

            });


await session.abortTransaction();
session.endSession();

    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log('Transaction error is:', error);
        await session.abortTransaction();
        session.endSession();
        res.status(503).send({ error: "Internal error." });
        // throw error; 
    }
    finally {

        if (session.inTransaction == true) {

            console.log('committing session');
            await session.commitTransaction();
            console.log('ending session');
            session.endSession();
        } else {
            console.log('session was aborted');

        }

    }

}
```

set of prints

```
createOrder req.body is :  {
  date: 1639251616628,
  price: '12.0',
  state: 'Waiting',
  collectedOnDate: 0,
  cancelledOnDate: null,
  customerFcmToken: 'dVes2tOhSyKiOg1RJNzViE:APA91bEBPj_5y9G_uuP5lFI5Iobjv_ikpfxnbtNmx5VUY9x74Cgci8Dl8SVSoDe5Gq7x7nw5GfD7DlDo-769MsfALeHcRuiz0CdO2J_m5x1Lof92mSQh5uPy2IpwuI_M5UMZfBktR1PM',
  customerId: '61af23dc02edbe24ce0344f4',
  customerName: 'vincenzo calia',
  shopId: '61ab9198262df7517970aed4',
  shopName: 'vincenzo calia',
  city: 'Bologna',
  region: 'Emilia-Romagna',
  country: 'Italy',
  productCategoryList: [ 'Safety and locks' ],
  productIdList: [ '61af8bec02edbe24ce034963' ],
  productPromotionList: [ false ],
  productNameList: [ null ],
  productPriceList: [ '12' ],
  isBuyNow: 'false'
}
session was aborted
Mongoose createOrder:  [
  {
    city: 'Bologna',
    region: 'Emilia-Romagna',
    country: 'Italy',
    date: 2021-12-11T19:40:16.628Z,
    price: '12.0',
    state: 'Waiting',
    collectedOnDate: 0,
    cancelledOnDate: null,
    customerFcmToken: 'dVes2tOhSyKiOg1RJNzViE:APA91bEBPj_5y9G_uuP5lFI5Iobjv_ikpfxnbtNmx5VUY9x74Cgci8Dl8SVSoDe5Gq7x7nw5GfD7DlDo-769MsfALeHcRuiz0CdO2J_m5x1Lof92mSQh5uPy2IpwuI_M5UMZfBktR1PM',
    customerId: '61af23dc02edbe24ce0344f4',
    customerName: 'vincenzo calia',
    shopId: '61ab9198262df7517970aed4',
    shopName: 'vincenzo calia',
    productCategoryList: [ 'Safety and locks' ],
    productIdList: [ '61af8bec02edbe24ce034963' ],
    productIsPromotionList: [],
    productNameList: [ null ],
    productPriceList: [ '12' ],
    isBuyNow: false,
    totalRating: 0,
    ratings: 0,
    _id: new ObjectId("61b4fea0d184bca49c82f2d0"),
    createdAt: 2021-12-11T19:40:16.607Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-12-11T19:40:16.607Z,
    __v: 0,
    averageRating: 0,
    id: '61b4fea0d184bca49c82f2d0'
  }
]
Mongoose Order.findOrderById:  {
  _id: new ObjectId("61b4fea0d184bca49c82f2d0"),
  city: 'Bologna',
  region: 'Emilia-Romagna',
  country: 'Italy',
  date: 2021-12-11T19:40:16.628Z,
  price: '12.0',
  state: 'Waiting',
  collectedOnDate: 0,
  cancelledOnDate: null,
  customerFcmToken: 'dVes2tOhSyKiOg1RJNzViE:APA91bEBPj_5y9G_uuP5lFI5Iobjv_ikpfxnbtNmx5VUY9x74Cgci8Dl8SVSoDe5Gq7x7nw5GfD7DlDo-769MsfALeHcRuiz0CdO2J_m5x1Lof92mSQh5uPy2IpwuI_M5UMZfBktR1PM',
  customerId: '61af23dc02edbe24ce0344f4',
  customerName: 'vincenzo calia',
  shopId: '61ab9198262df7517970aed4',
  shopName: 'vincenzo calia',
  productCategoryList: [ 'Safety and locks' ],
  productIdList: [ '61af8bec02edbe24ce034963' ],
  productIsPromotionList: [],
  productNameList: [ null ],
  productPriceList: [ '12' ],
  isBuyNow: false,
  totalRating: 0,
  ratings: 0,
  createdAt: 2021-12-11T19:40:16.607Z,
  updatedAt: 2021-12-11T19:40:16.607Z,
  __v: 0,
  averageRating: 0,
  id: '61b4fea0d184bca49c82f2d0'
}
```

Comment: Where is Order.create called? I don't see any obvious issues with the code - 
I personally believe it may be an issue with the payload structure you are sending to "create the order" - What is the code that causes the error?

Comment: @oblivion02 I think I found the issue. If I pass the object in an array as `Order.create( [req.body],{ session: session }, .. ` as specified here https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create then it gets created, but it's not rolled back if transaction is aborted. In finally{} statement  you can see I check if `session.inTransaction` is` true and then commit and end the session.. if `false` it means that the transaction was aborted. After creating the order I never get the `committing transaction` and `ending session` prints inside it. I get the `session was aborted`.

Comment: I also tried aborting the transaction just after the create method but it doesn't get rolled back, I get it on a get request passing its id. Does all this  mean the using create method as specified in the docs for transactions is actually committing the transaction terminating the session?

Comment: @oblivion02 I updated the question and the code sample to explain it better.

Comment: Have you tried `session.withTransaction` method instead, also this is minor thing I noticed. you have not added `await` for `session.abortTransaction`. And another thing would be `Object.create` could get executed after session has aborted, since you are not awaiting for Object.create to finish.

Comment: @v1shva well I did give it a go, but couldn't make it work so I tried starting the transaction manually, that was before finding out that I had to start mongo as a replica set and  in a transaction the object the object needs to be in an array as in `Order.create( [req.body],{ session: session }, .. `  as soon I can reconnect to my mongo I'll give `.withTransaction` another try. I upgraded mongoose to v6..1.1 an mongo to 5.0.4 and I get `ECONNREFUSED` error now..

Comment: @v1shva I added the logs in the question. even when awaiting to abort the session is the same.. 
One thing is strange dough.. I forgot to start my instance as a replica set and it didn't throw an error.. mmmm

Comment: I think still the session will get aborted before order.create executes, so that order.create will not belong to any session at the time of execution.

Comment: @v1shva following your thought I tried calling `session.abortSession` inside .create's function(err, result) {} but now I get the error `MongoTransactionError: Cannot call abortTransaction twice` and it's the only place I call it, I commented out the other ones

Comment: @v1shva yes not sure why but I solved it by checking `session.inTransaction()` as I did for choosing if commit the transaction or just end the session. Thank you for your help. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems that Model.create can't be undone upon aborting a transaction the only way I found to manage it ( not sure it's just a workaround or  the proper business logic) is to wrap it in a `if` statement checking the current state of the session `if (session.inTransaction()) {}` as I do in the `finally` statement to commit the transaction or simply end the session.

```
exports.createOrder = async (req, res) => {

...

            if (session.inTransaction()) {
                const order = {
                    city: city,
                    region: region,
                    country: country,

                    date: Date.now,
                    price: totalOrderAmount,
                    state: 'Waiting',
                    collectedOnDate: null,
                    cancelledOnDate: null,
                    customerFcmToken: customerFcmToken,
                    customerId: customerId,
                    customerName: customerName,
                    shopId: shopId,
                    shopName: shopName,
                    productCategoryList: productCategoryList,
                    productIdList: productIdList,
                    productIsPromotionList: productIsPromotionList,
                    productNameList: productNameList,
                    productPriceList: productPriceList,
                    isBuyNow: isBuyNow,
                    

                    stripePayment: stripePaymentIntent
                };


                await Order.create(
                    [order],
                    { session: session },
                    function (err, result) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log('Mongoose createOrder error:  Order.create', err);
                            session.abortTransaction();
                            responseCode = 503;
                            responseMessage = 'Internal error';
                            return;
                        }
                        console.log('Mongoose createOrder: ', result);
                        responseCode = 200;
                        responseData = result;
                        message = "Order created successfully!";
                    }).exec();
            }



        }
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log('Transaction error is:', error);
        await session.abortTransaction();
        session.endSession();
        res.status(503).send({ error: "Transaction error." });
        // throw error; 
    }
    finally {
        if (session.inTransaction()) {
            console.log('transacion wasn\'t aborted');
            console.log('committing session ');
            await session.commitTransaction();

        } else {
            console.log('transacion wasn aborted');
        }

        console.log('ending session ');
        await session.endSession();
        res.status(responseCode).send({
            message: responseMessage,
            data: responseData,
            unavailableProducts: unavailableProducts,
            unavailablePromotions: unavailablePromotions
        });

    }



}
```